# sonar always throwing duplicate exception, even with only a file

Tags: sonarqube

I'm struggling with sonar server and sonar runner (standalone via commandline). My project sonar file is:

```
# Required metadata
sonar.projectKey=org.codehaus.sonar:calculator
sonar.projectName=Calculator
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

# Comma-separated paths to directories with sources (required)
sonar.sources=src

# Language
sonar.language=py

# Encoding of the source files
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

And my command is

```
/opt/sonar-runner/bin/sonar-runner -Dsonar.projectBaseDir=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Servidor-RDS/serv/rdsweb/WebContent/fccma/js/fcc/tests/python-sonar-runner/ -Dproject.settings=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Servidor-RDS/serv/rdsweb/WebContent/fccma/js/fcc/tests/python-sonar-runner/sonar-project.properties
```

Nothing exotic. I haven't any project in sonar (I've delete all), and my project structure is 
src/
    myCaluclator/
        calculator.py
        **init**.py

Calculator code is:

```
class Calculator(object):
    def add(self, x, y):
        return x + y
```

I always get an:

```
Caused by: org.sonar.api.resources.DuplicatedSourceException: Duplicate source for resource: org.sonar.api.resources.File@7d3e8935[key=myCalculator/calculator.py,dir=myCalculator,filename=calculator.py,language=Python]
at org.sonar.batch.index.SourcePersister.saveSource(SourcePersister.java:45)
at org.sonar.batch.index.DefaultPersistenceManager.setSource(DefaultPersistenceManager.java:78)
at org.sonar.batch.index.DefaultIndex.setSource(DefaultIndex.java:456)
at org.sonar.batch.DefaultSensorContext.saveSource(DefaultSensorContext.java:161)
at org.sonar.api.batch.AbstractSourceImporter.parseDirs(AbstractSourceImporter.java:88)
```

Do I need to clean some cache or something?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you try running "/opt/sonar-runner/bin/sonar-runner" within "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Servidor-RDS/serv/rdsweb/WebContent/fccma/js/fcc/tests/python-sonar-runner/" folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution:
The sonar.sources is present in my sonar-runner properties and in my project properties, so all files are declared twice.

My error

Comment: I had the same problem while using Sonar with a Play2 project. I defined sonar.sources=app,test and sonar.tests=test. I had to remove test from sonar.sources property (if it can help others)

Comment: Thanks, this helped. I have a question, if I have sonar.tests=src/java-test,test/java (where test/java contains my Unit tests) and src/java-test contains Integration tests) and both have a file named: TestKoba.java, then I'm getting the above/similar error message about Duplicate source for resource. Now, What should I tell the Developer, to rename the file in src/java-test to something like IntegrationTestKoba.java? or remove src/java-test from sonar.tests variable (i.e. use "sonar.tests=test/java" only for Unit tests)?